# Mongodb, getting the id of the newly pushed embedded object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have embedded comments in a posts model. I am using mongoosejs. After pushing a new comment in a post, I want to access the id of the newly added embedded comment. Not sure how to get it.

Here is how the code looks like.

```
var post = Post.findById(postId,function(err,post){

   if(err){console.log(err);self.res.send(500,err)}

   post.comments.push(comment);

   post.save(function(err,story){
       if(err){console.log(err);self.res.send(500,err)}
           self.res.send(comment);
   })


});
```

In the above code, the id of the comment is not returned. Note there is a _id field which is created in the db.

The schema looks like

```
var CommentSchema = new Schema({
  ...
})

var PostSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    comments:[CommentSchema],
    ...
});
```

Comment: Where does `comment` come from?

Comment: its a json object which is created in another part of the code...above the one given.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A document's `_id` value is actually assigned by the client, not the server.  So the `_id` of the new comment is available right after you call:

```
post.comments.push(comment);
```

The embedded doc pushed to `post.comments` will have its `_id` assigned as it's added, so you can pull it from there:

```
console.log('_id assigned is: %s', post.comments[post.comments.length-1]._id);
```

Comment: Although, it has been marked as solved, but what if one is using $push to add the document in the array. How to fetch the id in that case.   
Example:    
       `let newValue = await model.findOneAndUpdate(
  { name: 'NEW Value', 'comments.name': {$ne: newComment.name} },
  { $push: {comments: newComment} },
  { new: true }
 ).exec();`

Answer (score 8):

You can manually generate the _id then you don't have to worry about pulling it back out later.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var myId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

// then set the _id key manually in your object

_id: myId

// or

myObject[_id] = myId

// then you can use it wherever
```

Answer (score 1):

`_id` field is generated at client side, you can get the id of the embedded document by `comment.id`

sample

```
 > var CommentSchema = new Schema({
     text:{type:String}
  })

 > var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     text:{type:String}
 })

 > var Story = db.model('story',StorySchema)
 > var Comment = db.model('comment',CommentSchema)
 > s= new Story({title:1111})
   { title: '1111', _id: 5093c6523f0446990e000003, comments: [] }
 > c= new Comment({text:'hi'})
   { text: 'hi', _id: 5093c65e3f0446990e000004 }
 > s.comments.push(c)
 > s.save()
```

verify in mongo db shell

```
    > db.stories.findOne()
{
    "title" : "1111",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5093c6523f0446990e000003"),
    "comments" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5093c65e3f0446990e000004"),
            "text" : "hi"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```